# Office Word Addin : Getting null or undefined error when call angular 6 service inside office context

Tags: angular

I am developing word officejs application with angular 6. Getting error while call this.anyservice or this.anyvariable inside Office.context.document.

Service is ,

```js
 @Injectable()
    
          export class OfficeService {
    
    constructor(private ngxXml2jsonService: NgxXml2jsonService) {
    }
    
    
    
    ReadData(){
    
       Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByNamespaceAsync("namespace", function (asyncResult) {
    
          this.ngxXml2jsonService = asyncResult
    
       });
    
     }
    
    }
```

I am assigning result Office.context.document to this.ngxXml2jsonService.

Getting error :  **Unable to set property 'ngxXml2jsonService' of undefined or null reference**

Even I tried to call another service , but still getting same error. Then I print console.log(this), so came to know that "this" also not accessible inside office.context.document.

I need a help to resolve this issue.

Comment: **NgxXml2jsonService** is it a service? If yes then you can not assign value to any DI instance.

Comment: Use arrow functions, your `this` context is getting lost

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain **this** instance in other variable, before calling your method of office.context...

Something like this:

```js
ReadData() {
  var self = this;
  Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByNamespaceAsync("namespace", function (asyncResult) {
      self.ngxXml2jsonService = asyncResult
  });
}
```

This is required as getByNamespaceAsync will be invoking your callback() function.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and, as recommended by @xyz, I used arrow function instead and that seems to allow me to access the context where **this** is defined. In your case it would be something like:

```
Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByNamespaceAsync("namespace",  (asyncResult) => {  
     this.ngxXml2jsonService = asyncResult
});
```

However, in my case at least, modifying the **this.variable** doesn't seem to be picked up by the component html where it's being referenced. Still researching...

---

Update:

UI wasn't updating because the code is being executed outside of Angular zone. As per Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-ins-with-angular2#trigger-the-ui-update), you'll need to add:

```
this.zone.run(() => {
  // the codes that need update the UI
});
```